# How I can search document with quote symbol in solr?

Tags: solr

How I can search with quote symbol in solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Escaping Special Characters](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

```
\(1\+1\)\:2
```